# Verify host certificate was signed by a root

Tags: java, android

I have an android application that will connect to a server. I would like the android application to be able to validate that the server cert was signed by a root certificate created by myself.

I've tried to add the root ca to my trust store:

```
InputStream rootCa = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.root_ca);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
trustStore.load(null,null);
trustStore.setCertificateEntry("serverRoot", cf.generateCertificate(rootCa));

SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Try to hit your server URL in a browser. Most likely the returned certificated/chain is not proper.

Comment: My browsers warns me because it is not a trusted root, but it correctly displays the certs chain as far as I can tell.

Comment: It looks like you are using `HttpClient`, but did you initialize it with the SSL factory you created? Show full code.